# regex to prepend NOT between word and punctuation

Tags: python, string, tokenize

I an trying to reproduce using regex the classical tokenization trick to deal with sentences like

```
"I didn't like that SO question, but I like pizza!"
```

The solution that has been proposed in the literature is actually very simple. Prepend with `NOT_` every token between "didnt' and the **next punctuation mark**. So in our example this becomes:

```
"I didn't NOT_like NOT_that NOT_SO NOT_question, but I like pizza!"
```

How can we do that using python or regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your attempt at code.

Comment: It does not work. I tried with positive lookbehind but I am struggling with the number of tokens to replace after that. No need to downvote for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokenize using regexes, then split and join like so:

```
import re
sentence = "I didn't like that SO question, but I like pizza!"
words = re.split("([,.?:!;]|didn't)", sentence)
not_sentence = "".join([word if (idx == 0 or words[idx-1] != "didn't")
                        else re.sub(r"(\w+)", "NOT_\\1", word)
                        for idx, word in enumerate(words)])
print(not_sentence)
# I didn't NOT_like NOT_that NOT_SO NOT_question, but I like pizza!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

text = "I didn't like that SO question, but I like pizza!"

regex = re.compile(r'(?<=didn\'t)(\s.+)+\,')

segment = regex.search(text).group(0)

result = text.replace(segment, segment.replace(' ', ' Not_'))

print(result)
"I didn't Not_like Not_that Not_SO Not_question, but I like pizza!"
```

Comment: nice one but what if I have multiple replacements to do in the same sentence? you cannot know if advance how many groups to have

Comment: You would just compile a regex to handle multiple replacements. Cheers! :)